# 11.04 upgrade to 14.10 fails

Tags: upgrade, 11.04, 14.10

I tried to upgrade with the manager but guess what? My version is 11.04 and the manager try to upgrade to 11.04.  What can I do and is it possible to upgrade through all those End-of-Life versions, step by step?

Answer (score 1):

You can theoretically upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 and then to 12.04, then just do a direct upgrade to the Trusty release.

There's many reasons why I will suggest, instead, backing up the data you want to keep and then just doing a clean install.  As you upgrade from version to version to version, you run the risk of more and more things breaking.  Especially when you go from a really old release to a newer release.

Comment: Ouch, that's a lot of backing up. I am in the same situation, ie I want to go from 11.04 to 14.10. Is there a way to do this without overwriting a certain folder, so I could copy stuff to one folder and keep it?